# Login with Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I want to integrate twitter login code to my website. I had created the application in twitter and I had Consumer key, Consumer secret. But I am not getting the code for integrating it. The integration must be in PHP.

Comment: I didn't asked for the exact code but the reference for the integration code in php.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+integrate+twitter+with+site&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=integrate+twitter+with+site&oq=integrate+twitter+with+site&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30l3.12711.12711.0.13129.1.1.0.0.0.0.301.301.3-1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.zKzZhEwUrII&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.eWU&fp=e7a1ab06a109c209&biw=1152&bih=669

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your answer...

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter

You have to implement it.